# How did they film the final shootout scene from Felina?

Tags: film-techniques, breaking-bad, effects

The [final shootout scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_D3KoxlonbM) in the last episode of *Breaking Bad* is quite impressive.  Since watching it, I've wondered how it was filmed.

When stepped through frame-by-frame, the rounds appear to be leaving real bullet holes and causing real damage.  Was it just incredibly good CGI?  Did they really shoot up a room and green-screen actors into it?

Answer (score 4):

The trace bullet are CGI. And probably are very easy to make. Just watch this Connan segment where they add the bullets at 4m 10sec mark.

The bullets holes are usually made with small controlled explosions. So the holes are real, just not really dangerous. But also can be made with CGI.

Very basic / Low Budget example:

if you want see how a real machine gun will looks like on this case. Check this mythbuster video:

Comment: This all makes sense, and it goes hand in hand with my understanding of how effects are usually added.  I was hoping for an answer that was specific to Breaking Bad, though -- maybe a behind-the-scenes clip or one of the creators talking about it.